# Are JavaScript closure variables referenced or do they contain their own copy?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have been reading on closures lately and am slightly confused and therefore have a few questions.

So i thought of a closure as anytime you use a variable from inside a function that is located somewhere outside of your immediate lexical scope. Another definition i often hear is.. 'Keeping a copy of the variables alive just as they were before the function had finished executing'.

So lets say i have a function with a private variable:

```
function foo() {
    var x = 'abc';
    return function() {
        return x;
    }
}

var bar = foo();
console.dir(bar) // [[Scopes]] - 0: Closure { x: 'abc' }
```

When i console.dir this and check what is inside the closure i am able to see that the property x has a value of 'abc'.

I am slightly confused as to how x stays 'Alive' inside the inner function when the parent (outer) function variables are discarded and garbage collected *(..i assume)* in javascript immediately after the parent function has been executed.

So when i return the inner function definition to the variable bar i assume somewhere that it also holds a reference and forms the closure as well? (Maybe i'm wrong this is where i am confused).

Also when i form a closure and the closure contains variables from its parent's scope, does it create a new copy of this variable and stores it in the closure or does it just reference the variable from outside the function and modifies its value? because i thought the variable 'x' would be discarded as soon as the parent function has executed?

Sorry for the silly and long winded question, but it would be nice if someone could clear this up abit for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a closure. Your function scope inherits its outer scope, which inherits its outer scope and so on. If in your scope you are using any variable from outer scope JS engine increases references counter of this variable and that's why it's not removed by garbage collector (it removes variables which are not referenced anymore, i.e. has 0 reference count).

Answer (score 0):

The inner function/closure contains a reference to the outer function/closure. And when you return the variable x, it will look up its value from the outer closure, which still exists.

Comment: If anyone could post some documentation to this, that would also be helpful.